# What is the C# equivalent of this code

Tags: c#, vb.net

This code is working fine in VB.Net how i convert it to C#.

```
 Dim alpha As String = "./;'[]<>?:""{}\|~!@#$%^&*()_+-=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
    If InStr(alpha, e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, this would be:

```
// Note the escaped string here: \\ instead of \, and \" for the quote
string alpha = "./;'[]<>?:\"{}\\|~!@#$%^&*()_+-=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";

if(alpha.Contains(e.KeyChar))
   e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: I think the string would be most appropriately represented using a verbatim string literal due to the double-doublequotes.

Comment: @Jeff: The doubled double-quotes are the escaped version for VB - it's just a single double quote in the string.  With a verbatim string, you'd still need to escape that, though.  I just converted them both to C#'s style, but you could do `@"./;'[]<>?:""{}`...

Comment: That being said, there's really no difference - it's a matter of how you prefer expressing it - using a @ with "" or a normal string with \" and \\

Comment: I know.  I was just suggesting it as by doing so, required no other changes to the string.  It could be used as-is prepended with `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Note the use of the ampersand (@) at the start of the string:

```
string alpha = @"./;'[]<>?:""{}\|~!@#$%^&*()_+-=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
if (alpha.IndexOfAny(new[] { e.KeyChar }) > -1) 
    e.Handled = true;
```

or a little more funky we can eliminate the `if` statement:

```
e.Handled = alpha.IndexOfAny(new[] { e.KeyChar }) > -1;
```

Comment: This won't compile - needs to be `alpha.IndexOfAny(new[] {e.KeyChar})`, since IndexOfAny expects a `char[]` - otherwise, you could use IndexOf

Comment: @Reed - yeah, good point :) Answer edited. I currently have a Silverlight project open, and the key up/down event handlers don't use KeyChar and it SL doesn't have the KeyPress event handler, so i had to make an assumption.

Answer (score -1):

```
string alpha = "./;'[]<>?:\"{}\\|~!@#$%^&*()_+-=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";

if(alpha.Contains(e.KeyChar))
e.Handled = true;
```

Besides that there is an excellent online tool that converts C# to VB.NET and vice versa
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: This, btw, is assuming a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, which won't exist (by default) in a C# project.  Without that, Strings.InStr will not exist.  (That's, btw, one problem with auto-conversion routines...)

Comment: `Strings.InStr(string, char)`? I think people who don't know the language should avoid using that tool.

Comment: @negative: From Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll assembly.  It exists, by default, in VB.NET projects, but not C# projects.

Comment: you are right. Missed that. No matter what, it's a really nice tool. :)